# Building a previous version from svn

Tags: maven, svn, release

What I want is to build the 1.1 release version of my project directly from svn. The current version number is 1.2-SNAPSHOT.
Is there any way to do that? I assume there is but I don't know the command.
If you need more information, please let me know I will provide it to you.
Thanks,
V.

Comment: What do you mean, "directly from svn?" Simply check out the tagged revision and run your Maven goals.

Comment: I mean that after executing a command (I know there isn't such a command but e.g. mvn clean install -DbuildVersion -DscmUrl=...) the maven would get the right source from SVN to a temporary folder, make a build and remove the checked out source. Is there such a command?

Comment: I doubt it. If you really want a singular command, why not write a Bash script that does the svn checkout and runs the Maven build?

Comment: Thanks Tom again! I just wanted to be lazy but it seems I can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such command to get source code to a temporary location + build it + clean up. You have to script it, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

work=$TMPDIR/builder-$$

cleanup() {
    rm -fr "$work"
}

trap 'cleanup; exit 1' 1 2 3 15

mkdir -p $work
svn co url/to/release/1.1 $work/
(cd $work; mvn clean install)

cleanup
```